# Java WebSocket HandshakeRequest getParameterMap method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

Does the method `getParameterMap` of the `HandshakeRequest` include path parameters? I can't seem to find a detailed documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HandShakeRequest#getParameterMap()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/HandshakeRequest.html#getParameterMap--) says following:

> Return the request parameters associated with the request.

It says request parameters, not path parameters.

Let's check how an URL is composed:

```
http://example.com/context/foo/bar?foo=bar&bar=foo
                  ----------------
                  Request URI
```

```
http://example.com/context/foo/bar?foo=bar&bar=foo
                  --------
                  Context path
```

```
http://example.com/context/foo/bar?foo=bar&bar=foo
                           --- ---
                           Path parameters
```

```
http://example.com/context/foo/bar?foo=bar&bar=foo
                                   ------- -------
                                   Request parameters
```

When having only `HandShakeRequest` at hands, which doesn't have any method directly returning path parameters, your best bet is to use [`getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/HandshakeRequest.html#getRequestURI--) and perform string manipulation (split, substring, etc) in order to extract path parameters.

The alternative is to move the task into [`Endpoint#onOpen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html#onOpen-javax.websocket.Session-javax.websocket.EndpointConfig-) or [`@OnOpen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/OnOpen.html), there path parameters are just directly available via [`Session#getPathParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#getPathParameters--).

Comment: thank you for that. I'll leave the Handshake alone and work on the OnOpen then.